# Handle Method not allowed in slim 3

Tags: php, slim-3

Need you help to figure this out. i developed my website in Slim 3 framework. I wanted to handle "**Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST**" message which i get when i am using browser back and forward buttons.

```
I want to redirect to a different page when if the route is post and when user clicks on browser back or forward page.
```

When the post route is called is there a way where i can detect the that it is post method call and redirect him to a different get route.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own handler for specific errors:

```
$container['notAllowedHandler'] = function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, array $methods) {
    // you can return a redirect response
};
```

see more [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/handlers/not-allowed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax solution

```
$notAllowedHandler = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {
        return $response
            ->withJson(
                [
                    "status" => false,
                    "message" => "Your custom message",
                    "data" => [],
                ]
            )
            ->withStatus(400);
    };
};

$app = new App(
    [
        'notAllowedHandler' => $notAllowedHandler,
    ]
);
```